# How would to check if a user visits a certain web url in a Windows Service application in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've been trying to find a way to check if a user visits a url (even if it doesnt exists) such as `http://127.0.0.1/apage` and whenever they visit this a page with html will show in a web browser. I'm more looking to how you would be able to check if they visited. I've been trying to Google my solution for many days now but with no luck unfurtunately.

This is what I have until now

```
        private Thread _thread;

        public Northwind()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        { 
            Thread myThread = new Thread(DoSomething);
            myThread.Start();
                // only checks if website exists 
            string url = "http://aweb.nl";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\map\service.log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Hello World " + DateTime.Now );
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
```

Comment: The straight forward way is if you own the site then you check from there and notify any listeners or simply log it. If you don't own it, you would need a network monitoring tool if you want to monitor users within your Network. If you don't own the site and want to monitor any access to it I would ask you why you would want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Options may include, Write a browser extension, write your own proxy, Dll inject all network apps from the kernel, write a filter driver, or use some 3rd party library

Comment: There are two ways coming to my mind to achieve what you want. 1. Easier: Your service can act as a web proxy. You listen on a specific port, and edit the registry to register 127.0.0.1 and this port as the proxy. You then act like a web proxy and return as you wish. 2. Implement a low level network driver and direct all the traffic through this driver by manipulating the network routing table (Uh..)